# $(s).position({ my: "center+0 top"}) shows with offset

Tags: jquery, position

I am using this plugin http://api.jqueryui.com/position/ to position element. If I do

```
$(s).position({
    my: "center top",
    at: "center top",
    of: '#main_container',
});
```

`$(s)` is being positioned by the center

but if I do

```
$(s).position({
    my: "center+0 top",
    at: "center top",
    of: '#main_container',
});
```

it moves a bit right from the center. Why does it offsets if there is offset +0?

Comment: Why does it offsets if there is offset +0?

Comment: Can we see it somewhere? Could you share a fiddle?